# I keep getting an error on Python, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int' What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

## Compound Interest Calculator

#Input

```
P = (float, input("Enter the starting principal: ") )
R = (float, input("Enter the annual interest rate: ") )
m = (int, input("How many times per year is the interest compounded? ") )
t = (float, input("For how many years will the account earn interest? ") )
```

#Calculate

#FV = P * ( 1 + ( (R/100) / m ) ) ** ( m * t)

```
FV = P * ( 1 + ( (R/100) / m ) ) ** ( m * t)
```

#Output

```
print("At the end of ", t, "years. You will have $", format(FV, ",.2f") )
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax:

```
input_variable = float(input("some text"))
input_variable= int(input("some text"))
```

Comment: wow I feel dumb thank u lol! omg I have been trying to fix it for hours what a simple fix thank you so much I am not good at programming still trying to learn!

Answer (score 0):

```
P = float(input("Enter the starting principal: ") )
R = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate: ") )
m = int(input("How many times per year is the interest compounded? ") ) )
t = float(input("For how many years will the account earn interest? ") )

FV = P * ( 1 + ( (R/100) / m ) ) ** ( m * t)

print("At the end of ", t, "years. You will have $", format(FV, ",.2f") )
```

The `float, input("bla bla bla"))` should be like `float(input("bla bla bla")))` and with `int, input("bla bla bla"))` change it to this: `int(input("bla bla bla"))`